# Why doesn't my formula calculate after I enter it?

Tags: excel, vba

I get an application defined error when my program enters this data into the cell.

```
Range("$H$7").Formula = "=S:/Finance/Budget & Forecast/2023/2023 Budget/Chapters/030 - New England/[030 - New England.xlsm]Consolidated'!" & Budget
```

It enters it fine if I don't include the "=" sign, but does not calculate. I thought making this a .formula instead of a .value would automatically do this formula's calculation. No?

I've tried researching this, and I've tried putting double quotes around the string portion, it gives me "compile error: expected line number or label or statement or end of statement".

Ultimately, I just want this to give me the results of this formula when VBA enters it, just as if I typed it in, but with the dynamic term Budget at the end giving me the cell address (which is populating fine, via vlookup).

Comment: Missing an opening `'`.

Comment: Regarding the error with the quotes, you'd need to _escape_ (double up) double quotes inside a string literal, because double quotes _delimit_ string literals.